# Samba file sharing with AD authentication doesn't work on some boxes

Tags: samba, samba4

I have a few RHEL7 boxes, all of them are members in MS Win domain using SSSD.
All of these linuxes run Samba for file sharing with the same config. 
Usually it works nice, but from time to time users cannot map Samba folders, with the following message in the log:

```
[2017/03/07 14:58:27.050493,  0] ../source3/auth/auth_domain.c:121(connect_to_domain_password_server)
  connect_to_domain_password_server: unable to open the domain client session to machine DC03.example.LOCAL. Error was : NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED.
[2017/03/07 14:58:27.050756,  0] ../source3/auth/auth_domain.c:184(domain_client_validate)
  domain_client_validate: Domain password server not available.
```

"From time to time"  - i.e., sometimes certain Samba box is broken for a long time, sometime some box is stopping  to work for some time.
Unfortunately, I cannot blame MS Win admins because in the same time some Samba boxes are OK when others are broken.
Any ideas?

My Samba is samba-4.4.4-12.el7_3.x86_64, config is

```
security = ADS
passdb backend = tdbsam
realm = EXAMPLE.LOCAL
password server = x.x.x.x y.y.y.y
```